# At which point do I get data for my app using redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am fetching all event data in my app.js:

```
store.dispatch(
  eventsFetchData(
    "http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/index.php/wp-json/tribe/events/v1/events"
  )
);

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppNavigation />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

However I need a drop down list on my first page, where users can select a category. I only need to show events for the chosen category.

Where would I fetch my categories to populate my select list? I can then do a fetch for only the events in that category.

Here is my select list using hardcoded data, which I would like to get from an api:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

import { setSelectedView } from "../actions/events";
import { navigate } from "../navigation/actions";
import Picker from "./common/Picker";

import * as theme from "../theme";

class HomeScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};

        this.onGroupChange = this.onGroupChange.bind(this);
        this.onYearChange = this.onYearChange.bind(this);
    }

    onYearChange(e) {
        if (e !== null) {
            this.props.dispatch(setSelectedView(e));
        }
    }

    onGroupChange(e) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Month");
    }

    render() {
        const studentYears = [
            {
                id: 0,
                label: "Year 1",
                value: 1,
                options: ["Firm 1", "Firm 2", "Firm 3"]
            },
            {
                id: 1,
                label: "Year 2",
                value: 2,
                options: ["Firm 2", "Firm 3", "Firm 4"]
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                label: "Year 3",
                value: 3,
                options: ["Firm 5", "Firm 6", "Firm 7"]
            }
        ];

        let selectedView = this.props.selectedView;

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image
                    source={require("../img/logoGreen.png")}
                    style={{ width: 300, height: 200 }}
                />

                <View style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
                    <Picker
                        selectedValue={selectedView}
                        label="Year"
                        onChange={this.onYearChange}
                        options={studentYears}
                    />
                    {selectedView
                        ? <Picker
                              selectedValue="0"
                              label="Year group"
                              onChange={this.onGroupChange}
                              options={studentYears[selectedView].options}
                          />
                        : null}
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        events: state.events,
        hasErrored: state.eventsHasErrored,
        isLoading: state.eventsIsLoading,
        selectedView: state.setSelectedView
    };
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeScreen);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#6da1a6",
        flex: 1
    },
    logo: {
        flex: 1,
        width: 300,
        height: 100,
        resizeMode: "contain"
    }
});
```

So the order of state should be,

1. Homescreen loads categories from api and populates select list.
2. User chooses category. A further select list should appear where the user chooses the a subcategory.
3. Main event data is loaded,determined by chosen subcategory.
4. User is taken to main events screen/ calendar.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the fetch of the data in the `componentDidMount(){ ..here..}` function in the Homescreen component. When you get the data you can:

-Either put it inside the Homescreen class state which means that you should do `this.setState({...fetchedData})`

*Note that you have to handle empty data in the picker in the beginning since you will not have the data immediately.*

-Or you can dispatch a redux function with the data you have fetched

`this.props.dispatch(action(data))`

in this case you need to add the redux state that contains the data to your Homescreen component with the `mapStateToprops` function, you will find the data in this.props.YOUR_MAPED_STATE when you get the data.

Comment: "Note that you have to handle empty data..." the reducers used for the store should be stubbing out the appropriate empty objects/collections so that the `mapStateToProps` function can act as a simple transform on data, allowing the component to act as a simple view with minimal logic.

Comment: Thats right, but its still the case when using `this.state` if not using default or empty values.

Comment: likewise, `this.state` should be stubbed out in the constructor with the appropriate empty objects/collections.